# need to track # of times a video is opened/viewed on a Samsung Galaxy tablet. How?

Tags: samsung, video, tablet-apps

I work for a company in Africa that works with smallholder farmers. One way that we try to improve our farmers' experiences is through showing them video of agricultural techniques and other subjects. The videos are all put on Samsung Galaxy Tab3 or 4 tablets and shown to the clients in the field. I need to know how many times the video is open and being shown to clients. The current video application we use does not track number of times viewed or open. Does anyone have a suggestions for an app or another way that I can track this? Thanks.

Comment: which video application you are using?

Comment: I am using a VLC player app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android secret code `*#*#4636#*#*` to track the usage time of the video player. While that does not give you the *number* of times video player has been opened, it should give you a fair indicator of the number of times (= usage / video duration ). The secret code needs to be entered on the dialpad of your telephone app

This app does the same and is an alternate to the secret code - [4636](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kei5rio.secretcode). Screenshot of usage time on my device below. You have options to track usage as shown

( Thanks to OP for highlighting another app [App Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.uninstaller) that worked but 4636 didn't)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The tablet I have is a samsung Galaxy Tab 3, can you direct me to where I could find these usage statistics?

Comment: or where I go to enter the secret code?

Comment: Enter it exactly the way it is

Comment: Thanks! The 4636 did not work on my tablet.  But I found a similar application called App usage app that does exactly what you explained above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this input, added that to the answer to help others in future. Continue to use our site