# Nexus 5x won't use 3G since Android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, nexus-5x

Since I lost my p8lite I had to buy a new phone, thus a mew SIM card was given to me. I'm still on the same contract which covers all signal types. Ranging from E-4G I live in an area  with 3-4/5 bars of 4G I can't receive any 3G anywhere. Even with 3G option forced on. If anyone knows a way to use 3G it would help me stop using data so fast and I would appreciate it.

Comment: Tried the classic *#*#4636#*#* ("asterisk hash asterisk hash 4636 hash asterisk hash asterisk", in case SE's markdown interprets it wrong) trick yet? Disable LTE from there.

Comment: I don't know where your trying to send me in the options.

Comment: Worked it out bit it says "connection problem or invalid MMI code"

Comment: Couple of apps mentioned in this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160177/131553) do the same as that secret code does. See if either of them work and you are able to disable LTE