# Need help in changing "Preferred Network Type" on rooted and unlocked LG G2 LS980

Tags: rooting, mobile-network, lg-g2

I need to change "Preferred Network Type" in Phone Info in Testing apk on my  LG G2 LS980, like in this screenshot from a Youtube video.

[image]

In the dialer, I type `*#*#4636#*#*`

[image]

Which opens the Testing apk as below, with following 4 options:

[image]

I can open Battery Information, Usage statistics and WiFi information as below:

[image]

But when I open the Phone Info menu, it says `This application does not work on this device`

[image]

My phone is running on Android 5.0.2, Software Version LS980ZVG (flashed with Stock ROM) and rooted. It is unlocked to use in India.

Comment: see if any of the apps mentioned in [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160177/131553) can help. Two apps are mentioned

Comment: @beeshyams: I don't see any application names in the thread.

Comment: Look at my answer there - 4636 and app usage are mentioned and linked