# Full App Usage History

Tags: recents-screen

The procedure described here (code `*#*#4636#*#*`):

https://thegeekpage.com/view-app-history-android-even-someone-cleared/

worked fine in my phone. Is there another way to obtain a full log of each time an app was executed?

It could be a log-like history, with a chronological order with a timestamp and app executed (icon clicked). No need for CPU usage. A recent (~1 day) list would suffice.

Edit: my device is a Motorola Moto C Plus with Android 7.0.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160177/131553

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the app mentioned there does not work on my device. I've edited the question to add my android version.

Comment: Plenty of apps on Play Store - search for "app usage tracker". This one is recently updated. Not tried by me https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.uninstaller